# C int to char converstion adds garabge characters

Tags: c++, c, arrays, casting

I am trying to convert an int into 4 bytes. for some reason it ends up adding some garbage special character at the end

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int num = 31070;

    char arr[4];

    arr[0] = num & 0xFF;
    arr[1] = (num >> 8) & 0xFF;
    arr[2] = (num >> 16) & 0xFF;
    arr[3] = (num >> 24) & 0xFF;

    return 0;
 }
```

Here is an output of the debug window wherein you can see that it adds `^` and `y` for `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`

[image: Debugger output window]

I have tried things like casting but still have these garbage characters getting added.

Comment: It seems the data is displayed as character since it is in character type variable. Use another debugger or seek for setting to disable them if you hate it.

Comment: You are misunderstanding the debugging output. It is just telling you that `94` is the character `'^'` and same for the other character. It's trying to be helpful by giving you extra information. Just ignore it if it is not helpful for you.

Comment: Try using the `uint8_t` type.  When playing with bits, `unsigned` types are always preferred.

Comment: doesn't the order of your bit shifts and bitwise ands reverse the bytes of the int?  Unless you are intending to read it from index 3 to 0 order.

Comment: I see thanks a lot guys.

Comment: @Cody Yep I intend to read 3 to 0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are not garbage characters. Those are the ascii representation of the decimal number. The debugger is just showing you the ascii representation. Look for 94 and 121 on this table:

http://www.asciitable.com/